Visual Studio no Code-Behind all of a sudden
Been working fine using visual studio 19 with a WPF powershell project, until the other day whenever i go to event handelers for any button i get the below error,
“The document item has no code-behind file. Add a code-behind file and class definition before adding event handlers”
Hoping someone can help and point me in the right direction. I updated Visual Studio the day before this happened. Now even when creating a new project i get the same error.
Thanks

Based on your description, It may be a problem with your Visual Studio configuration. Could you please tell me the exact version of Visual Studio you are using and how you created the PowerShell WPF project in Visual Studio? I can try to see if I can find anything.
Additionally, since you mentioned the Visual Studio update, have you checked the compatibility of your extensions with the new version of Visual Studio? Some extensions might be incompatible after an update.

I think i figured it out.. I use Powershell Tools from Ironman and that seems to be the issue. I installed on another machine and its the same... So looks like the new version of this has caused the isssue.
I am working with Powershel Projects then add item which is a WPF Powershell window.
